# python setuptools setup, module installed, file structure seems ok but not working

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, setup.py

I have this tool that I want to share in my community. I want it to be added to paths so they run it from terminal. I don't understand why I get this error. I went through all the examples I could find and it is not working for me. I have spend more time on doing the setup file than the actual program. What should be the structure then? The script's structure is simple

```
.
|____databases
| |____GER.json
| |______init__.py
| |____ENG.json
|____sameWidther.py
|____getKern
| |______init__.py
| |____flatten_gpos_kerntable.py
|______init__.py
```

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='sameWidther',
    version='0.1',
    description='The funniest joke in the world',
    url='http://github.com/storborg/funniest',
    author='Jan Šindler',
    author_email='jansindl3r@gmail.com',
    license='MIT',
    packages=['sameWidther', 'sameWidther.databases', 'sameWidther.getKern'],
    package_data={
        "sameWidther.databases": ["*.json"],
    },
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "sameWidther = sameWidther.sameWidther:main",
        ]
    },
    zip_safe=False)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jansindler/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/bin/sameWidther", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('sameWidther==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'sameWidther')()
  File "/Users/jansindler/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sameWidther-0.1-py3.8.egg/sameWidther/sameWidther.py", line 148, in main
    run(args.parser)
  File "/Users/jansindler/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sameWidther-0.1-py3.8.egg/sameWidther/sameWidther.py", line 130, in run
    with open(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'databases/ENG.json'
```

module in site-packages, it is interesting that the databases and getKern folder were duplicated. Though the structure should still work

```
.
|____databases
| |____GER.json
| |______init__.py
| |____ENG.json
|____sameWidther.py
|____getKern
| |______init__.py
| |____flatten_gpos_kerntable.py
|______init__.py
```

Comment: Please show `sameWidther.py` around line 130.

Comment: @hoefling ahh, I was blind. I was disappointed after 3 hours of trying and lost my eyes. Now after you mentioned to check it again, it was because the file was set relatively, but I didn't set that it should be relative to the file. Also naming the folder and the file the same created a lot of confusion :) I will answer the question later, when someone has the same problem!